# List Comprehension retornando zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, dicionário

Galera, preciso da ajuda de vocês.
Estou com um código em python que gostaria que retornasse a quantidade de valores que atendem a um critério, porém esta retornando zero.
O arquivo txt contém dados como esse:

```
567886786765211267878783647866575678666869837678681226786789 cancelado

562342342342343123124234534645656756756756756756756765756178 assinado

555456456546544324234235434534645645645645654645645645645631 assinado

520757345873458374657834857897989988786785645342111575756432 cancelado

554234534534645647567867987089078655345231342536456575676777 cancelado
```

Esse é o retorno que estou tendo:

```
{'P1': {'Total': 2, 'Ativos': 0}, 'P2': {'Total': 2, 'Ativos': 0}, 'P3': {'Total': 1, 'Ativos': 0}}
```

E eu gostaria que ele me retornasse assim:

```
{'P1': {'Total': 2, 'Ativos': 0}, 'P2': {'Total': 2, 'Ativos': 1}, 'P3': {'Total': 1, 'Ativos': 1}}
```

Esse é o código

```
with open('log.txt','r') as file:
    arquivo = filter(None, [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in file])

prefixo = []
    status = []
    for linha in arquivo:
        prefixo.append(linha[0][:2])
        status.append(linha[1])
    data = zip(prefixo, status)
    
paises = {
    'P1': {
        'Total': [p for p in prefixo if p == '55'].count('55'),
        'Ativos': [d for d in data if d[0] == '55' and d[1] == 'assinado'].count('assinado')
    },
    'P2': {
        'Total': [p for p in prefixo if p == '56'].count('56'),
        'Ativos': [d for d in data if d[0] == '56' and d[1] == 'assinado'].count('assinado')
    },

    'P3': {
        'Total': [p for p in prefixo if p == '52'].count('52'),
        'Ativos': [d for d in data if d[0] == '52' and d[1] == 'assinado'].count('assinado')
    },
}
```

Se puderem me ajudar

Comment: Sem ver o arquivo (estou assumindo que tem, por causa do `for linha in arquivo`), só nos resta tentar adivinhar: coloque `[ d[1] for d in data etc...` (em vez de só `d for d in data`). De qualquer forma, poderia [edit] e colocar algumas linhas do arquivo como exemplo?

Comment: @hkotsubo eu estava tentando editar a postagem e não estava conseguindo. Vou editar, porém não posso compartilhar o arquivo.

Comment: @hkotsubo eu fiz a alteração que você mencionou, porém continua com o mesmo resultado

Comment: Não precisa ser o arquivo inteiro, pode ser só um pedaço que reproduz o problema, senão a gente não consegue nem testar, e muito menos saber o que está errado... Ou, mude os dados pra algo que possa ser divulgado, desde que o problema principal permaneça (a contagem dê zero). Senão a gente vai ficar nessa adivinhação ("tente isso", "não deu"), e como vc percebeu, não é nada produtivo

Comment: hkotsubo dá uma olhada e vê se consegue entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) retorna um iterável que só pode ser percorrido/iterado uma vez. Exemplo:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
z = zip(x, y)

print('primeira vez:', [ d for d in z ])
print('segunda vez:', [ d for d in z ])
```

A saída deste código é:

```
primeira vez: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
segunda vez: []
```

Pois na primeira vez eu percorro todos os elementos do iterável, e na segunda vez não tem mais o que percorrer. Por isso suas contagens resultam em zero, pois a partir da segunda vez que você percorre o `data`, não tem mais nenhum elemento, e por isso a contagem é zero.

Uma forma - não muito eficiente - de resolver seria colocar o conteúdo em uma lista:

```py
data = list(zip(prefixo, status))
```

E nas *list comprehensions* você tem que pegar o elemento que corresponde ao status (ou seja: `[d[1] for d in data if d[0] == '55' and d[1] == 'assinado'].count('assinado')`).

Mas essa solução é ineficiente porque depois você percorre várias vezes a mesma lista, e chama `count` várias vezes (sendo que cada chamada de `count` percorre a lista novamente). Sem contar que você está colocando todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma lista (se ele for muito grande, será um gasto desnecessário de memória).

Uma solução melhor é ler o arquivo linha a linha e ir atualizando o dicionário a cada linha lida. Um exemplo de como ficaria:

```py
def get_pais(prefixo): # não precisa do slice [:2], basta ver se começa com os dígitos
    if prefixo.startswith('55'):
        return 'P1'
    elif prefixo.startswith('56'):
        return 'P2'
    elif prefixo.startswith('52'):
        return 'P3'
    return None

paises = {}
with open('log.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo: # lê o arquivo linha a linha
        dados = linha.rstrip('\n').split()
        if len(dados) != 2: # se a linha não tem todos os dados, vai para a próxima
            continue
        prefixo, status = dados # separa o prefixo e o status
        pais = get_pais(prefixo)

        if pais is not None: # se o país é válido
            if pais not in paises:  # se o país ainda não está no dicionário paises
                paises[pais] = { 'Total': 0, 'Ativos': 0 }
            paises[pais]['Total'] += 1
            if status == 'assinado':
                paises[pais]['Ativos'] += 1
```

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: @EduardoLopes Deve ter linha em branco no arquivo. É por isso que a gente pede pra colocar um pedaço dele, em vez de só uma linha...

Comment: hkotsubo existe essa possibilidade de haver espaços em branco entre uma linha e outra. Com 
 esse código arquivo = filter(None, [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in file]) é possível remover esses espaços

Comment: @EduardoLopes Não precisa disso. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: hkotsubo realmente não precisa de um filter. Percebi que o gasto de memória para cada nova inserção de informação no arquivo, seria realmente muito custoso.

Comment: Muito obrigado @hkotsubo, esclareceu muita coisa. Como eu posso manter contato com você?

Comment: @EduardoLopes Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Sobre contato, basta continuar participando do site que estou sempre por aqui